# Analysis: limit notation when the function value approaches some value

Tags: real-analysis, limits, notation

Is an expression such as the following mathematically admissible?

$$\lim_{h(x) \to h_1} f(x)$$

where $f, h: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are some continuous functions and $h_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Motivating examples are

$$\lim_{x + y \to 0} (x+y) = 0$$

and

$$\lim_{x^2 + y^2 \searrow 0} (x^2 + 2 y^2 + y ) = 0$$

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to express by that?

Comment: Doesn't look ok to me. $h(x) \to h_1$ suggest a limit process, so unpacking this into something meaningful will most likely lead to a double limit.

Comment: @Phicar I've seen only limit notation such as x->x0. But I wonder whether a limit of a function f(x) is well defined when the function value h(x) approaches some value, while the way that x moves is not specified.

Comment: The second example seems weird since it seems that you’re just saying $x+y\to 0$. But aren’t you saying $\lim_{n \to\infty} (x_n+ y_n) \to 0$ and third could just be written as $\lim_{x\to 0;\, y\to 0}\,(x^2 +y^2) = 0$?

Comment: In the first case, if $Q = h^{-1}(h_1)$. If it is just one point $q$ then you can write $\lim_{x \, \to \, q} f(x)$. Otherwise you could restrict X to a connected set with only one $q\in Q$ as a limit point.

Comment: In the first comment last line, I meant $\lim_{x,y \downarrow 0} x^2 +2y^2+y$

Answer (score 1):

I learned topology and logic recently. I tried to apply my new knowledge to this question.

Let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. For some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $l \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{h(x) \rightarrow \alpha} f(x) = l
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align}
&\forall \epsilon > 0 :\exists\delta > 0 : \forall x \in X:\Vert h(x) -\alpha\Vert < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-l| < \epsilon\\
&\forall \epsilon > 0 :\exists\delta > 0 : \forall x \in X: h(x) \in B_\delta(\alpha) \Rightarrow f(x) \in B_\epsilon(l)\\
&\forall \epsilon > 0 :\exists\delta > 0 : \forall x \in X: x \in h^{-1}[B_\delta(\alpha)] \Rightarrow x \in f^{-1}[B_\epsilon(l)]\\
&\forall \epsilon > 0 :\exists\delta > 0 : h^{-1}[B_\delta(\alpha)] \subseteq f^{-1}[B_\epsilon(l)]
\end{align}
$$
If we can find such $\delta$ for each $\epsilon$, whatever $f$ and $h$ are, we can conclude that $f(x)$ converges to $l$.

This question was originally posted after seeing the notation in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radially_unbounded_function)